# Bluetooth: how to solve "not enough free handles to register service" error?

Tags: sound, bluetooth, toshiba, lsusb, bluetooth-speaker

Since a couple of weeks I'm having an annoying problem. The connection switch in bluetooth is greyed out:

[image: bluetoooth]

So in order to re-establish a connection, I have to re-pair the devices (a bluetooth speaker in this case). Even this takes a couple of tries before it succeeds.

So i looked to my bluetooth status, which shows some errors:

```
sudo service bluetooth status -l
```

[image]

so i went further to see from which hardware manufacturer my bluetooth adapter is

```
lsusb
```

[image: lsusb]

Seems some proprietary  from toshiba?

Anyway, how can i solve this "not enough free handles" problem please? In the past, it worked without to many problems (it did occur that i have to repair them, but only once in a while). Maybe it is caused by an kernel update?

(ps: i'm running ubuntu 15.10 x64)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was solved by upgrading to 16.04

Comment: I don't think so. [See this Launchpad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/1490349).

Comment: I haven't encountered the problem since running 16.04. For me the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Check `rfkill` service. It could block connections sometime for LAN, Wifi and Bluetooth.

You can check what is blocked with this command:

```
rfkill list
```

My bluetooth was blocked. I used this command:

```
rfkill unblock bluetooth
```

So now "not enough handlers" error is gone and BT works as it should