# Ubuntu 16.04 cannot connect to soundlink revolve

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio

I have a Bose revolve sound link that I would like to connect but it cannot seem to be seen as a audio output device in the sound settings.

The bluetooth manager can find it:

[image]

Based on some similar questions

- [How to get Bose Soundlink Mini Bluetooth Working](https://askubuntu.com/q/453125/645490)

I have all the packages required installed, but have the following issue with the `sudo pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover` command:

```
user:~$ sudo pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
Home directory not accessible: Permission denied
Connection failure: Connection refused
pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused
```

(Initially I was getting a module initialisation error but have followed the file edits listed here [PulseAudio can not load bluetooth module 15.10/16.04/16.10](https://askubuntu.com/a/689297/645490))

In order to try and solve this file permission issue I did a `chown` to `user:user`as suggested by [pulseaudio not working : “Home directory not accessible: Permission denied”](https://askubuntu.com/a/338574/645490)

While the speaker is apparently connected and paired:

[image]

Trying to set it up as an audio sink using the bluetooth manager (blueman-manager)

[image]

gives

> Device added successfully, but failed to connect

All I want is to play music without a cable using bluetooth. Please help.

**Output from `dmesg`**:

As per the comments:

```
user:~$ dmesg | grep -i blue
[    2.001587] thinkpad_acpi: rfkill switch tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: radio is unblocked
[    3.011106] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[    3.011121] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.011125] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.011128] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.011133] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    3.071385] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware revision 0.0 build 176 week 45 2017
[    3.154634] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    3.154637] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    3.154641] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   17.072559] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   17.072567] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   17.072572] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  364.861714] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 2 week 52 2014
[  364.868660] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 5
[  364.868682] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[  364.868684] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[  364.868686] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[  364.868688] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[  364.868693] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[  364.874079] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-11-5.sfi
[  366.557166] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[  366.557321] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1657881 usecs
[  366.557577] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
[  366.569358] Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 11666 usecs
[  366.571206] Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-11-5.ddc
[  366.575471] Bluetooth: hci0: Applying Intel DDC parameters completed
[  450.141876] Bluetooth: SMP security requested but not available
[ 1083.993183] Bluetooth: SMP security requested but not available
[ 1231.253271] Bluetooth: SMP security requested but not available
[ 1241.243098] Bluetooth: SMP security requested but not available
[ 2155.113184] Bluetooth: SMP security requested but not available
[17079.840115] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 2 week 52 2014
[17079.847101] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 5
[17079.847113] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[17079.847121] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[17079.847128] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[17079.847135] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[17079.847145] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[17079.851993] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-11-5.sfi
[17081.456649] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[17081.456937] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1580614 usecs
[17081.457090] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
[17081.468974] Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 11693 usecs
[17081.475381] Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-11-5.ddc
[17081.479011] Bluetooth: hci0: Applying Intel DDC parameters completed
```

where the output display from the bluetooth settings can detect the device but cannot seem to pair:

[Bluetooth list of devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dClU.png)

But as I mentioned, the device is not listed on the list of audio output sources:

[Audio output devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voj2E.png)

**Output from `/var/log/syslog`**

Abbreviated slightly due to character limit (I have copied all the bits containing the word bluetooth).

```
Jul  4 15:06:58 nb-infomm16-12 kernel: [23806.809863] Restarting tasks ... 
Jul  4 15:06:58 nb-infomm16-12 kernel: [23806.822067] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 2 week 52 2014
Jul  4 15:06:58 nb-infomm16-12 kernel: [23806.829951] done.
Jul  4 15:06:58 nb-infomm16-12 kernel: [23806.833760] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 5
Jul  4 15:06:58 nb-infomm16-12 kernel: [23806.833764] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
Jul  4 15:06:58 nb-infomm16-12 kernel: [23806.833766] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
Jul  4 15:06:58 nb-infomm16-12 kernel: [23806.833767] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
Jul  4 15:06:58 nb-infomm16-12 kernel: [23806.833768] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
Jul  4 15:06:58 nb-infomm16-12 kernel: [23806.833770] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
Jul  4 15:06:58 nb-infomm16-12 kernel: [23806.834051] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-11-5.sfi
Jul  4 15:06:58 nb-infomm16-12 systemd[1]: bluetooth.target: Unit not needed anymore. Stopping.
Jul  4 15:06:58 nb-infomm16-12 systemd[1]: Stopped target Bluetooth.
Jul  4 15:07:00 nb-infomm16-12 kernel: [23808.284169] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
Jul  4 15:07:00 nb-infomm16-12 kernel: [23808.284634] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1440239 usecs
Jul  4 15:07:00 nb-infomm16-12 kernel: [23808.284709] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
Jul  4 15:07:00 nb-infomm16-12 kernel: [23808.295648] Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 10720 usecs
Jul  4 15:07:00 nb-infomm16-12 kernel: [23808.296012] Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-11-5.ddc
Jul  4 15:07:00 nb-infomm16-12 kernel: [23808.299680] Bluetooth: hci0: Applying Intel DDC parameters completed
Jul  4 15:06:59 nb-infomm16-12 whoopsie[2716]: [16:06:59] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Jul  4 15:07:00 nb-infomm16-12 bluetoothd[1434]: Failed to obtain handles for "Service Changed" characteristic
Jul  4 15:07:00 nb-infomm16-12 bluetoothd[1434]: Not enough free handles to register service
Jul  4 15:07:00 nb-infomm16-12 bluetoothd[1434]: Error adding Link Loss service
Jul  4 15:07:00 nb-infomm16-12 bluetoothd[1434]: Not enough free handles to register service
Jul  4 15:07:00 nb-infomm16-12 bluetoothd[1434]: message repeated 2 times: [ Not enough free handles to register service]
Jul  4 15:07:00 nb-infomm16-12 bluetoothd[1434]: Current Time Service could not be registered
Jul  4 15:07:00 nb-infomm16-12 bluetoothd[1434]: gatt-time-server: Input/output error (5)
Jul  4 15:07:00 nb-infomm16-12 bluetoothd[1434]: Not enough free handles to register service
Jul  4 15:07:00 nb-infomm16-12 bluetoothd[1434]: Not enough free handles to register service
Jul  4 15:07:00 nb-infomm16-12 bluetoothd[1434]: Sap driver initialization failed.
Jul  4 15:07:00 nb-infomm16-12 systemd[1]: Reached target Bluetooth.
Jul  4 15:07:00 nb-infomm16-12 bluetoothd[1434]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
Jul  4 15:07:01 nb-infomm16-12 ModemManager[750]: <info>  Couldn't check support for device at '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:04:00.0': not supported by any plugin
Jul  4 15:07:01 nb-infomm16-12 ModemManager[750]: <info>  Couldn't check support for device at '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.6': not supported by any plugin
Jul  4 15:07:04 nb-infomm16-12 bluetoothd[1434]: Unable to register GATT service with handle 0x0001 for device 04:52:C7:F9:4C:D0
Jul  4 15:07:04 nb-infomm16-12 bluetoothd[1434]: Unable to register GATT service with handle 0x0013 for device 04:52:C7:F9:4C:D0
Jul  4 15:07:19 nb-infomm16-12 ModemManager[750]: <info>  Creating modem with plugin 'Generic' and '1' ports
Jul  4 15:07:19 nb-infomm16-12 ModemManager[750]: <warn>  Could not grab port (tty/ttyS4): 'Cannot add port 'tty/ttyS4', unhandled serial type'
Jul  4 15:07:19 nb-infomm16-12 ModemManager[750]: <warn>  Couldn't create modem for device at '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.3': Failed to find primary AT port
Jul  4 15:07:29 nb-infomm16-12 bluetoothd[1434]: Unable to register GATT service with handle 0x0001 for device 04:52:C7:F9:4C:D0
Jul  4 15:07:29 nb-infomm16-12 bluetoothd[1434]: Unable to register GATT service with handle 0x0013 for device 04:52:C7:F9:4C:D0
Jul  4 15:07:44 nb-infomm16-12 dbus[801]: [system] Activating service name='org.blueman.Mechanism' (using servicehelper)
Jul  4 15:07:44 nb-infomm16-12 org.blueman.Mechanism[801]: Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Jul  4 15:07:44 nb-infomm16-12 org.blueman.Mechanism[801]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Jul  4 15:07:44 nb-infomm16-12 org.blueman.Mechanism[801]: Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Jul  4 15:07:44 nb-infomm16-12 org.blueman.Mechanism[801]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Jul  4 15:07:44 nb-infomm16-12 blueman-mechanism: Starting blueman-mechanism
Jul  4 15:07:44 nb-infomm16-12 dbus[801]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.blueman.Mechanism'
Jul  4 15:07:44 nb-infomm16-12 org.blueman.Mechanism[801]: (blueman-mechanism:1358): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
Jul  4 15:07:44 nb-infomm16-12 blueman-mechanism: loading Network
Jul  4 15:07:44 nb-infomm16-12 blueman-mechanism: loading Rfcomm
Jul  4 15:07:44 nb-infomm16-12 blueman-mechanism: loading Ppp
Jul  4 15:07:44 nb-infomm16-12 blueman-mechanism: loading RfKill
Jul  4 15:07:53 nb-infomm16-12 kernel: [23861.775248] Bluetooth: SMP security requested but not available
Jul  4 15:08:12 nb-infomm16-12 systemd[3106]: Time has been changed
Jul  4 15:08:12 nb-infomm16-12 ntpd[2741]: receive: Unexpected origin timestamp from 193.52.136.2
Jul  4 15:08:12 nb-infomm16-12 systemd[1]: Time has been changed
Jul  4 15:08:15 nb-infomm16-12 blueman-mechanism: Exiting
Jul  4 15:08:37 nb-infomm16-12 kernel: [23904.285184] Bluetooth: SMP security requested but not available
Jul  4 15:08:37 nb-infomm16-12 kernel: [23904.285215] Bluetooth: SMP security requested but not available
Jul  4 15:08:37 nb-infomm16-12 kernel: [23904.285394] Bluetooth: SMP security requested but not available
Jul  4 15:08:37 nb-infomm16-12 bluetoothd[1434]: Unable to register GATT service with handle 0x0001 for device 04:52:C7:F9:4C:D0
Jul  4 15:08:37 nb-infomm16-12 bluetoothd[1434]: Unable to register GATT service with handle 0x0013 for device 04:52:C7:F9:4C:D0
```

Comment: Have you tried not using bluetooth manager but simply go to ubuntu sound settings and change the output device to the bose resolve soundlink?

Comment: @BernardWei The issue is that is it not listed as an output device.

Comment: Can you add the last few lines from the output of 'dmesg' regarding the connection error? May be that will give some clue on why it failed.

Comment: One other thing, does it work with the handsfree profile? See also, https://askubuntu.com/questions/423169/get-the-bluetooth-audio-sink-working-with-kubuntu-13-10-and-bose-mini-soundlink?rq=1

Comment: You are right, can't see any failure in this log. So you have put the device into pairing mode but pairing failed. This is puzzling, may be it is logged in syslog, can you check if the pair failing logs is in there in /var/log/syslog

Comment: The device is currently listed as paired in the bluetooth settings, but still not an audio output device.

Comment: Look suspiciously like this problem, see if this one will help your case. https://askubuntu.com/questions/757396/bluetooth-how-to-solve-not-enough-free-handles-to-register-service-error . I have similar something similar, paired a mouse, then repaired the mouse to another machine. When I try to repair in Ubuntu, resetting the mouse won't work and I have to delete the device and repair.

Comment: No luck, bluetooth hasn't been blocked, and the device pairs fine and plays fine from my phone.

Comment: You probably know this already but just in case. Some bose unit support multiple devices, you can check the pair devices by pressing the bluetooth button usually. Also, when paired with multiple device, the active device must not be active or the unit will not allow a second device to play sound through it.

Comment: No other devices have been connected while I've been trying this, and the device has been repeating "ready to pair" throughout.

Comment: That may not meant much as the bose unit can be paired with multiple devices. The reason I brought this up is that the error show that the problem is with GATT connection, that usually meant the audio sink is not free and bose unit refuse to allow your ubuntu machine to connect. See this regarding GATT, https://learn.adafruit.com/introduction-to-bluetooth-low-energy/gatt

Answer (score 3):

As no one has posted an answer yet, I'll post a few solutions to try and it will hopefully inspire others with more experience to post answers.

## See what others have tried

From ***Unix & Linux*** site there is this Q&A: [How to pair Bose Soundlink Bluetooth using pulseaudio in Linux Mint Debian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159881/how-to-pair-bose-soundlink-bluetooth-using-pulseaudio-in-linux-mint-debian-edi):

```
sudo nano /etc/bluetooth/audio.conf # Insert lines below & save
[General]

Disable=Socket
Enable=Media,Source,Sink,Gateway
```

Then the commands:

```
sudo service bluetooth restart
sudo pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
sudo pactl load-module module-switch-on-connect
```

**Don't try these steps as is, Read the entire answer!**

### Answers in Ask Ubuntu

Another answer worth checking out is: [How to get Bose Soundlink Mini Bluetooth Working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453125/how-to-get-bose-soundlink-mini-bluetooth-working)

---

## Another method of gathering log info

With Ubuntu 16.04 and greater you can open a terminal and type `journalctl --follow`. Then perform various GUI actions such as bluetooth pairing and see system messages in real-time. This gives you a **systemd** alternative to `dmesg`.

Below is log output from `journalctl --follow` where:

- Bluethooth visibility was turned on
- Sony external speaker was set for pairing
- Attached Motorola phone which was previously paired to speaker was woken up to turn off the phone's bluetooth

#### `journalctl` sample log:

```
$ journalctl --follow
-- Logs begin at Mon 2018-03-05 05:53:18 MST. --
Jul 07 09:49:05 alien dbus[762]: [system] Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_return", sender=":1.34" (uid=0 pid=1527 comm="/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd -E ") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.63" (uid=1000 pid=2519 comm="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-bluetooth/indi")
Jul 07 09:49:40 alien kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: resuming kernel object tree...
Jul 07 09:49:41 alien kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: resuming client object trees...
Jul 07 09:49:41 alien kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: resuming display...
Jul 07 09:49:41 alien kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: resuming console...
Jul 07 09:49:46 alien kernel: ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
Jul 07 09:49:46 alien kernel: ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP: failed to evaluate _DSM
Jul 07 09:49:46 alien kernel: ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
Jul 07 09:49:46 alien kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: suspending console...
Jul 07 09:49:46 alien kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: suspending display...
Jul 07 09:49:46 alien kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: evicting buffers...
Jul 07 09:49:46 alien kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: waiting for kernel channels to go idle...
Jul 07 09:49:46 alien kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: suspending client object trees...
Jul 07 09:49:46 alien kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: suspending kernel object tree...
Jul 07 09:51:20 alien kernel: usb 1-1.4.4: new high-speed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
Jul 07 09:51:20 alien kernel: usb 1-1.4.4: New USB device found, idVendor=22b8, idProduct=2ea4
Jul 07 09:51:20 alien kernel: usb 1-1.4.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jul 07 09:51:20 alien kernel: usb 1-1.4.4: Product: Moto E (4)
Jul 07 09:51:20 alien kernel: usb 1-1.4.4: Manufacturer: motorola
Jul 07 09:51:20 alien kernel: usb 1-1.4.4: SerialNumber: ZY224VD3MX
Jul 07 09:51:20 alien mtp-probe[17678]: checking bus 1, device 13: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.4"
Jul 07 09:51:20 alien mtp-probe[17678]: bus: 1, device: 13 was not an MTP device
Jul 07 09:51:21 alien kernel: usb 1-1.1: usbfs: interface 0 claimed by usblp while 'brscan-skey-0.2' sets config #1
```

There might be other messages the system is generating at the same time that you might to ignore.

### Turning bluetooth speakers on

Using the systray GUI, when clicking the <kbd>Off</kbd> to turn it <kbd>On</kbd> this message appears in the terminal:

```
Jul 07 10:14:32 alien bluetoothd[1527]: Unable to get Headset Voice gateway SDP record: Host is down
```

Because the speakers have no microphone so the message is trivial.

---

## Bose Revolve Soundlink troubleshooting

From [here](https://www.ifixit.com/Wiki/Bose_Soundlink_Revolve_Troubleshooting) it suggests:

### Bluetooth Will Not Pair

*Your Bluetooth device will not pair to the speaker.*

### Speaker isn't in Bluetooth Mode

Make sure your speaker is in Bluetooth mode by pressing the Bluetooth button on the speaker while it is on. When the speaker is ready to pair, the LED next to the Bluetooth button will flash blue, and, if the voice prompts are on, the speaker will say, "ready to pair".

### Bluetooth isn't Turned on or Enabled on Your Device

Make sure the Bluetooth for your device is turned on or enabled and try to pair it again.

### The Device You are Trying to Connect to the Speaker to may be Out of Range

The speaker's wireless range is 30 feet. Make sure that the device you are trying to connect to the speaker is within that range and try to pair it again.

### There is Something in Between Your Device and the Speaker

Make sure there isn't anything between your device and the speaker, like bodies, walls, etc. and try to pair it again.

### Multiple Paired Devices

Only one device can be connected to the speaker at a time. If there are two devices paired to the speaker, turn off the Bluetooth on the device you don't want to be connected to the speaker and try to pair the device you do want to be connected to the speaker.

### There Have Been Eight Devices Connected to the Speaker

The speaker can only store information about the last eight devices that were paired with it. To select your device, repeatedly press the Bluetooth button on the speaker until you hear the name of your device. If you don't hear your device's name, clear the speaker's device memory. To clear the memory and connect your device, press and hold the Bluetooth button on the speaker until you hear a tone and, if voice prompts are enabled, you will also hear a voice prompt. Then the Bluetooth light will begin flashing blue and you can try to connect your device to the speaker again.

### The Speaker's Motherboard May be Faulty

First, factory reset the speaker by pressing and holding the power button while the speaker is on until the speaker asks you to select a language and there is a flashing blue light. Select a language and try to connect your device to the speaker again. If your device still won't connect to the speaker, consider replacing the motherboards as a last resort.